# How to associate Enter key to one of the many commandButtons on VF page

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

I have a Visualforce page with 3 buttons. One of button on clicking it will do a search and display the results on the same page. While other 2 buttons take the user to the next page. Also, I have a text boxes for the user to enter search text.

Now, the issue is when i hit enter key while i am in one of the text boxes it activates other button and takes the  user to next page which i do not want. I want to activate the Search button action. How could i achieve it? Any suggestions please.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, the submit button that appears first in the HTML is used when the user hits enter. Maybe you can reposition the buttons? This Stackoverflow question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963245/multiple-submit-buttons-specifying-default-button.
You can also maybe try to do something with Javascript, capture the enter button, trigger search and cancel submission of the form.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an action function that is called by the button and can be called from JS
2. Trap the enter key using a document.keypress event and call the action function if enter was the key pressed

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/submit-a-form-with-the-enter-key

Comment: Or, you can jQuery `$("#buttonId").click()` or something similar, but the effect is the same.